Gradle properties in Spring banner
I'm recently moving from maven to gradle and I would like to access some project variables as I was doing in maven, from my application.yml.
In my other project I would define in my pom.xml
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My API</name>
    <description>Backend Service for my API</description>

And in my application yml I would write this
info:
  build:
    name: @project.artifactId@
    description: @project.description@
    version: @project.version@


So in my banner I could do this
Powered by Spring Boot ${spring-boot.version}
${application.name}
${application.description}


what is the equivalent for this in gradle??
I've already tried



springBoot  {
    buildInfo()
}

processResources {
    expand(project.properties)
}

ext {
    group = findProperty('group')
    version = findProperty('version')
}


task writeVersionProperties {
    doLast {
        file('src/main/resources/version.properties').text = "application.version=${version}"
    }
}
bootRun {
    dependsOn writeVersionProperties
}

But yet nothing worked

In order to have gradle substitute properties in your application.[properties|yaml|yml], you will need to include:
processResources { expand(project.properties) }

This will process all file located in /src/main/resources/ and replace all ${..} tokens with gradle's project properties.

I've already tried this as well, but it stops compiling with my custom banner
Execution failed for task ':processResources'. > Could not copy file '/foo/bar/src/main/resources/banner.txt' to '/foo/bar/build/resources/main/banner.txt'. > Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed: SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy: 1: Unexpected character: '"' @ line 1, column 13. out.print(""" ___________ __ _
